# Disallowed Key Characters in json_decode in Codeigniter with Ampersand &

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I send a string to my controller that contains an &. When I do json_decode, it returns Disallowed Key Characters in that string.

Ex:

```
"1204" : {
"phone" : {
  "0" : "666666"
},
"idcontact" : "1211",
"firstName" : "User1",
"address" : {
  "0" : {
    "State" : "Madrid",
    "Country" : "Spain",
    "City" : "Madrid"
  }
},
"urls" : {

},
"company" : "Restaurant & Cafe Bar",
"birthday" : "1987\/03\/09",
"email" : {
  "0" : "user@restaurant.com"
},
"job" : "Owner",
"lastName" : "LastName"}
```

It returns..

```
Disallowed Key Characters: Cafe Bar",
____"birthday" : "1987\/03\/09",
____"email" : {
______"0" : "user@restaurant.com"
____},
____"job" : "Owner",
____"lastName" : "LastName"}
```

I tryed to change function _clean_input_keys($str) but I don't know how to do it.

How can I solve it?

Comment: `Encode` your string

Comment: It is encode, that's why I need to decode it

Comment: Because an ampersand is not an allowed character in JSON. `urlencode()` your string before converting it to JSON.

Comment: I tried to validate your example string at: [JSONLint - The JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/). It is not valid. If edited to be valid JSON, by enclosing in braces, then it decodes just fine in PHP. The '&' is perfectly valid in JSON and decodes correctly in PHP (5.3.29). No need to escape it or encode it. I put your JSON in a 'nowdoc'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding '&' in `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` in config file?

Comment: This is absolutely nothing to do with the URI. It is the json_decode function of PHP which is returning the error.